# How to minimize IE Browser using C# ?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, c#-4.0, window, minimize

How can I minimize the IE Browser using C#? I tried the code mentioned below which didn't work:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("*iexplorer.*");

if (processes.Any()) 
{

    var handle = processes.First().MainWindowHandle;
    ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED); 

}
```

Are there any other methods to achieve minimizing of the IE Browser?

Comment: Why? The browser belongs to the user, not your app.

Comment: for a more general solution, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254037/how-to-programmatically-minimize-opened-window-folders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Damien says, there is no fullproof way to do this as the user owns the browser, not your app. Your code isn't working because you are trying to use a wildcard symbol (*) like you would do on Google, but this doesn't work here. `GetProcessesByName` is literally looking for a process named `*iexplorer.*`. You can confirm this by placing a breakpoint underneath this line, and hovering over `processList`, it is an empty array. Changing this to `iexplore` fixes this problem.

Some tested and working code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        static void Main()
        {
            var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");

            foreach (var process in processes)
            {
                ShowWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```