# Process won't start minimized in c#

Tags: c#, firefox, process

```
pro.StartInfo.FileName =  @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";

pro.StartInfo.Arguments = a;
pro.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;

pro.Start();
```

I have this code above which starts Firefox minimized. but Firefox does not actually start minimized but as a normal window. What is the problem with my code? Do I have to sleep the thread for 100 ms ?

Comment: By "normal window" you mean it starts at it's default size?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov  I mean pops up like maximized

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473343/how-to-minimize-ie-browser-using-c-sharp, but use "firefox" as the process name for the accepted answer

Comment: @AlanH Well nothing again. I have changed firefox settings in 'about:config' so that it does not pop any crashes. May be that a problem?

Comment: @Dionisis: What are you talking about? Click the link `Alan H` posted and check out the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try out this one :)

```
pro.StartInfo.FileName =  @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";

pro.StartInfo.Arguments = a;
pro.UseShellExecute = true;
pro.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;

pro.Start();
```

As I think this will only work if firefox is NOT running. Else it will still open firefox, but not minimized. If you want to minimize your own starting firefox if the process is already up, you will need to handle `ShowWindow` as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Nah it didn't work. I want to start firefox minimized. There is no firefox window opened while i am doing this.

Answer (score -1):

to start a process without opening a terminal windows one can do like this:

```
 ProcessStartInfo pro = new ProcessStartInfo();

 pro.FileName = 'pathToFile'
 pro.RedirectStandardInput = true;
 pro.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
 pro.Arguments = 'some arguments'
 pro.UseShellExecute = false;
 pro.CreateNoWindow = true; // <- imp. line
```