# Process.Start url with hidden WindowStyle

Tags: c#, url, process, styles, webclient

I have a url that authenticates my credentials on a server. Is there a way to make it invisible? The simple code looks exactly like this:

```
public void DoAuth()
    {
        String uri = GetUri();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(uri);
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Process.Start(startInfo);

    }
```

however `ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden` doesn't seem to do the trick. If I set `UseShellExecute` to false then I get `Win32Exception` with the message `The system cannot find the file specified`
The url is a authentication on Spotify server to get the playlists and it looks something like this `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/client_id=26d287105as12315e12ds56e31491889f3cd293..`

Is there an other way to make this process invisible?

Edit: http sample

```
public void DoAuth()
    {
        String uri = GetUri();

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        HttpWebResponse webResponse;
        try
        {
            webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", webResponse.StatusCode);
            using (Stream data = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
            {
                //do what here?
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

The entire .cs file containing the sample above:

```
using SpotifyAPI.Web.Enums;
using SpotifyAPI.Web.Models;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace SpotifyAPI.Web.Auth
{
    public class ImplicitGrantAuth
    {
        public delegate void OnResponseReceived(Token token, String state);

        private SimpleHttpServer _httpServer;
        private Thread _httpThread;
        public String ClientId { get; set; }
        public String RedirectUri { get; set; }
        public String State { get; set; }
        public Scope Scope { get; set; }
        public Boolean ShowDialog { get; set; }

        public event OnResponseReceived OnResponseReceivedEvent;

        /// <summary>
        ///     Start the auth process (Make sure the internal HTTP-Server ist started)
        /// </summary>
        public void DoAuth()
        {
            String uri = GetUri();

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            HttpWebResponse webResponse;
            try
            {
                webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", webResponse.StatusCode);
                using (Stream data = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
                {
                    //nothing
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }


            /*ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(uri);
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            Process.Start(startInfo);
            */
        }

        private String GetUri()
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/?");
            builder.Append("client_id=" + ClientId);
            builder.Append("&response_type=token");
            builder.Append("&redirect_uri=" + RedirectUri);
            builder.Append("&state=" + State);
            builder.Append("&scope=" + Scope.GetStringAttribute(" "));
            builder.Append("&show_dialog=" + ShowDialog);
            return builder.ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Start the internal HTTP-Server
        /// </summary>
        public void StartHttpServer(int port = 80)
        {
            _httpServer = new SimpleHttpServer(port, AuthType.Implicit);
            _httpServer.OnAuth += HttpServerOnOnAuth;

            _httpThread = new Thread(_httpServer.Listen);
            _httpThread.Start();
        }

        private void HttpServerOnOnAuth(AuthEventArgs e)
        {
            OnResponseReceivedEvent?.Invoke(new Token
            {
                AccessToken = e.Code,
                TokenType = e.TokenType,
                ExpiresIn = e.ExpiresIn,
                Error = e.Error
            }, e.State);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This will stop the internal HTTP-Server (Should be called after you got the Token)
        /// </summary>
        public void StopHttpServer()
        {
            _httpServer.Dispose();
            _httpServer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And they are called like this:

```
_auth.OnResponseReceivedEvent += _auth_OnResponseReceivedEvent;
_auth.StartHttpServer(8000);
_auth.DoAuth();
```

The github url with a full runnable sampe is here: https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET
Download it and run the Spotify Test to connect to Spotify's web api to reproduce the sample I have.

Comment: That's not how broswers work; you can't do that.  You may want to send a direct HTTP request (but beware of cookies)

Comment: @SLaks I thought about that but what kind of request? And what should I do with the response? Don't I have to set the cookies on that request?
I will update a small sample of how I understand what you say

Comment: What do _you_ want to do with the response? That's entirely up to you.

Comment: @SLaks that's the problem here. Normally I do nothing with the response. As far as the connection is done then there is an open socket on the connection and I can get the playlists from Spotify. I will attach the entire .cs file so you can check the entire code if you have the time and will

Comment: What kind of project are you using ? for a .net process you don't have to have any UI

Comment: @MicahArmantrout You can find a full sample here: https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET. Spotify.dll provides a sample with the web api. The authentication done in the dll is the .cs file on the first post.

Comment: @MicahArmantrout you can download and run the sample provided there.

Comment: So 1) *is there a way to make a process invisible?* http://stackoverflow.com/a/30414483/495455 and 2) *The Edit?*, Its not clear what the problem is? I ran the ExampleForm and used the HttpWebRequest as per your edit and it ran fine, what were you expecting?

Comment: @ I am expecting to make it invisible. I am not sure I understand how the process for the authentication is done. I just want to make it invisible.
A http request would make it invisible but I don't know how I can combine it with the app so the tcp keeps listening as long as it takes.

As I said, the main goal is to make it invisible, one way or another.

Comment: Library author speaking. I **think** you are asking the wrong question for your problem. Do you want to hide the window or do you want authorization without user-action? Hiding the window will just open the login-page, but how would you interact with the local browser and click its buttons? `ImplicitGrantAuth` **can't** be used with simple HTTP-Requests, it uses multiple redirects and also Client-JS Code

Comment: @JohnnyDellinger I want to authorize it without user-action... Got me. Hope I find a solution here

Comment: @JohnP. Posted an answer, simulating a browser is one solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic XY-Problem, you are not searching for a way to hide the window, [you want to authenticate a user without user-actions involved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962235/process-start-url-with-hidden-windowstyle?noredirect=1#comment61965701_36962235).

Since `ImplicitGrantAuth` won't work with simple HTTP-Requests, you need a workaround:

#### Authenticate without user-action: Headless Browser

While `ImplicitGrantAuth` was not made for this kind of task, it's still possible but not cleanly. You will need a headless browser which you can control in your C# App, like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/%20Selenium).

Consider following code using Selenium ([related SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334065/how-do-i-use-selenium-in-c)):

```
void DoAuth()
{
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(GetUri());
    IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("username")); //You need to search for the correct element
    query.SendKeys("username");
    query = driver.FineElement(By.Name("password"));
    query.SendKeys("password");

    //Somehow submit the form and wait till you get the Token via URL
    //Thread.Sleep(5000);
    String urlWithToken = driver.Url;

    //Analyze it and get the token out of it

    driver.Quit();
}
```

This is just pseudo-correct code, but you should get the idea. Use a headless browser which you can control, fill in all form inputs, submit and analyze the URL. Facebook-Login would be the same principle.

**But note:** OAuth was not designed for this type of use and you propably should not use such hacky workarounds in production

Comment: Isn't it possible to be done with any http request? As far as I am seeing in the Spotify developer site, I can see it is... If not can you explain why in case you understand?

Comment: @JohnP.  `ImplicitGrantAuth` can't be issued just with HTTP-Requests. `ClientCredentialsAuth` can, because it won't have access to any user-information and needs your `Client-Secret key`. The whole sense behind OAuth is, that the user has to specifically grant your app access to his data before you can access it. If it would be possible with simple HTTP-Requests, the user's password has to be transmitted which spotify wouldn't like for sure.

Answer (score 3):

The entrypoint of a GUI program on Windows is the famous [WinMain() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  It looks like this:

```
  int CALLBACK WinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow
  );
```

The hInstance and hPrevInstance arguments are legacy and date back to Windows versions <= 3, versions that did not have support processes yet and required an app to take care of multiple instances of a task itself.  The lpCmdLine argument are the command line arguments.

`nCmdShow` is the important one and the subject of your question.  Expected values are SW_HIDE, SW_SHOWNORMAL, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZE or SW_SHOWMINIMIZE.  You can easily map them yourself to the possible ProcessWindowStyle enum values.

It is also exposed in the properties of a shortcut on your desktop.  For example:

[image]

I expanded the Run combobox, note the match with the ProcessWindowStyle enum values.  Except `Hidden`, hint of trouble there.

---

A typical C program passes the `nCmdShow` argument directly to the ShowWindow() function to display the main window (error checking omitted):

```
   HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
```

You'd be happy with such a program.  It is however not the way many programs actually work.  They **check** the value of `nCmdShow` and explicitly filter out `SW_HIDDEN`.  Or they restore the window state that the user last used.  In other words, they do this:

```
   HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
   if (nCmdShow == SW_HIDDEN) nCmdShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
   if (HasPreviousWindowState) nCmdShow = PreviousWindowState;   // optional
   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
```

---

This is for a done for good reasons.  Restoring the previous state is an obvious usability preference, many users will prefer it works that way for a browser for example.  I do.

More to the point for the missing `Hidden` option in the shortcut configuration dialog, both the OS and well-designed GUI programs intentionally avoid creating a usability nightmare.  Where the program gets started but there is no way for the user to activate the program.  There is no taskbar button for a hidden window.  Alt+Tab does not work.  The only way the user can regain control over the program is to terminate it with Task Manager.  It is also exploitable, malware could start a program and commandeer it and the user never notices.

All good reasons why such a program prevents this from happening.  Nothing you can do about it, the program overrides your choice and has the last say about it.

Comment: It took me some time reading and re-reading this to understand.
What about http connection instead of a browser that is built. It could be possible couldn't it? It is just luck of knowledge I believe. I am null in tcp connections and http processes but I do believe there must be a way to do what is being done here with http instead of browser.

Answer (score 2):

Go into the project properties in Visual Studio and change your project type to Class Library.  Save it.  Then change it to Windows Application and save.

That should get rid of any UI you are not explicitly creating yourself.

Comment: Completely irrelevant.

Comment: @John. P. - It answers the question "how to make a headless application in Visual Studio".  I think I can be forgiven for wondering what web requests have to do with that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to start a new process to get authorization from Spoitfy. You should make a Get/Post call and get authorization token and then include it in your future API calls.

```
GET https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize
```

I am referring to Spoitfy's online help page.

```
https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/
```

Comment: I've read that help page houndred of time. Still don't know how to do that request. But at least you understood what I want. It is a progress!

Comment: That is not the case according to @Johnny Dellinger

Comment: I am wondering if it will be blocked by using an automate browser.