# How to Minimise other windows while your application is running C#

Tags: c#

I need to minimize all other windows while my application is running. Is there a better way to do it using APIs?

Comment: While there probably is a technical way to do this, this seems like a monumentally bad design choice for an application. Would you have to keep minimizing windows that was opened/restored after your application has started and is still running? Having one application just imposing its will on *other* applications is almost always a bad design.

Comment: This is a requirement, needs to restrict users to it as long as it runs

Comment: That is a different question. Are you saying you have to prevent people from alt-tabbing to other applications or whatnot while your program is running? What you're looking for is [Kiosk mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/set-up-a-kiosk-for-windows-10-for-desktop-editions).

Comment: That's already done using keyboard hook, I need to minimize other apps which the user  might be running on second monitor.

Comment: Related post - [Minimizing all open windows in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/785054/465053)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following class and Call the method `MinimizeAll();` to do it.

Try this code:

```
using System;  
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class WindowMinimize
{

    const int SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7;
    // Hide other windows


    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    static void MinimizeWindow(IntPtr handle)
    {
        ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE);
    }


    public static void MinimizeAll()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process thisProcess =
           System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        System.Diagnostics.Process[] processes =
           System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
        try
        {
            foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process process in processes)
            {
                if (process == thisProcess) continue;
                System.IntPtr handle = process.MainWindowHandle;
                if (handle == System.IntPtr.Zero) continue;
                MinimizeWindow(handle);
            } //loop
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    } 
}
```