# show window while in full screen

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, windows, winapi

how can I show a window when I play a movie in full screen without exiting full screen mode of the movie player? I just want the window to apear on topof the movie. I know this is posible because yahoo messeger does it every time it showes you that a pearson has signed in or out , and I'm sure that there are other programs that do it also but I just can't remember now.

it can be in C/C++ mfc, win api , c# , wpf it doesn't mater.

Answer (score 3):

Just show the window with a z-order that places it on top of the full screen window.  I think you can do this by calling `SetWindowPos` passing `HWND_TOP`.  Something like this:

```
SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
```

You may want to include `SWP_NOACTIVATE` as well, or possibly some of the other `SWP_***` options. You can check the *uFlags* parameter in the [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28VS.85%29.aspx) function for the different `SWP_***` messages.

Answer (score 0):

C#
Use SetForegroundWindow() of user32.dll

More on stackoverflow
[C# Force Form Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46030/c-force-form-focus)

```
    // Sets the window to be foreground 
    [DllImport("User32")]
    private static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);
    // Activate or minimize a window 
    [DllImportAttribute("User32.DLL")]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
    private const int SW_SHOW = 5;
    private const int SW_MINIMIZE = 6; private const int SW_RESTORE = 9;
    private void ActivateApplication(string strAppName)
    {
        Process[] pList = Process.GetProcessesByName(strAppName);
        if (pList.Length > 0)
        {
            ShowWindow(pList[0].MainWindowHandle, SW_RESTORE);
            SetForegroundWindow(pList[0].MainWindowHandle);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

SetForegroundWindow will bring the player out of the full screen mode ,  and BringWindowToTop won't work. All other methodes sugested work if the window is from the same aplication as the video player, but what  I need is to put a window in from of a video player ( which is in full screen ) that is from another aplication.