# Find info about a window

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi

I found out the Yahoo Messenger window that notifies you when someone signs in or out is the only window that actually appears on top of a full screen movie or game and won't force you to exit full screen.

So my question is how can I find out what makes this window behave like this? I tried Spy++ but nothing interesting came up.

Comment: i think you need to edit your question to ask your ACTUAL question - how to do what Yahoo is doing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [show window while in full screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077502/show-window-while-in-full-screen)

Comment: You already asked this question. I gave an answer that I believe should work. Why won't you work with the previous question and sort it out that way? You can't just keep asking the same question again and again just because you asked it badly the first time round and weren't prepared to try to understand the answers.

Comment: tenfour is right.  Do you want to find out how Yahoo Messenger is achieving the window or do you want a general way to find certain information on various programs' behavior.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do this.  Some video card drivers on older versions of windows will behave differently.

1) Grab the desktop hwnd and paint to it.

```
HWND hwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
RECT rect = {};

GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect); // dimensions of the primary monitor are rect.right,rect.bottom

// Use hdc to paint whatever you want to the screen
```

2) Just create a top-most window without a titlebar and use the WS_EX_TOPMOST style.  Then draw whatever you want on it

```
CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be using the [windows notification API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#display_notification) (I don't have Yahoo messenger, so I'm not sure). Here's some more information about the notification area:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511448.aspx

Comment: I'm not quite sure about this , because I found a tutorial on this stuff http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf_notifyicon.aspx and it's using the windows notification API and the bad part it doesn't work , it doesn't apear in full screen lyke Y.Messenger does.